How to use sentinel with PHPRedis 6.0.2
I want to use redis sentinel for my project but when i try to this code i got this error. how can i fix that have u any suggestion?
session.save_handler = redis;
session.save_path = "tcp://10.10.10.100:6379,tcp://10.10.10.100:6379";

Error:
Fatal error: Uncaught RedisException: READONLY You can't write against a read only replica. in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:

I tried to write sentinels ip and masters name but error changed like as follows
Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: redis
